# Customize legend with discrete labels for heatmap with continuous but binned data

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, heatmap

I have created a heatmap in ggplot with continuous temperature data and scale_fill_viridis_c:

[image: heatmap continuous]

To make it easier to read I am testing a binned version with scale_fill_viridis_b and n.breaks:

[image]

My problem is that the binned heatmap legend shows ALL level labels, in this case every degree. I prefer to show only 5 or 6 labels in the legend. What I want is to keep the resolution in the plot an legend colours, but only label some of them (eg 0, 3, 6, 9, 12).

I have tried setting the labels manually with labels=c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12), but R complains that breaks and labels are different lengths. I want that but can't have it... I have also considered to mutate the whole data set, but would rather not since it is quite large, and also contains other data than temperature.

I know I should include a working sample of code and data, but I hope my question is straightforward enough to answer anyways. I would appreciate any help on how to format the legend of a binned heatmap, to show a smaller number of labels than the number of breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could label only some of the breaks by assigning an empty string aka `""` as the label for breaks you don't want to label. To this end I use an `ifelse` wrapped in an anonymous function which can be passed to the `labels=` argument of `scale_fill_viridis_b`.

Using some fake example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- expand.grid(
  x = seq(10),
  y = seq(10)
)
dat$temp <- seq(0, 14, length.out = 100)

ggplot(dat) +
  geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = temp)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_b(
    option = "turbo",
    n.breaks = 14,
    labels = \(x) ifelse(
      x %% 3 == 0, x, ""
    ),
    guide = guide_colorsteps(show.limits = TRUE)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Outstanding! This one works perfectly in my code, truly generic. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight forward question but some sample code would definitely make it easier. This appears to be a job for `scale_fill_manual()`. In the below case I randomly make a 10x10 raster and only label the 5th and 9th bins:

```
library(ggplot2)
rows <- 10
cols <- 10

data <- expand.grid(
  x = 1:cols,
  y = 1:rows
)

data$value <- sample(0:13, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)

# Only show 5 and 9 as labels in the legend
legend_labels <- c(5, 9)

# make a heatmap/raster in ggplot
heatmap <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = as.factor(value))) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = rainbow(14, start = 0, end = 1),
    breaks = as.character(0:13),
    labels = ifelse(as.integer(as.character(0:13)) %in% legend_labels, as.character(0:13), "")
  )
```

For a more generic solution that allows for user defined bin widths and label intervals over many locations or data sets you could use a function like this:

```
heatmapper <- function(data, value_col, label_interval = 5) {
  
  # Make pretty breaks at whole numbers. by= sets the the value interval for each bin that will be shown
  breaks <- seq(floor(min(data[[value_col]])), ceiling(max(data[[value_col]])), by = 1)
  
  # Factorize the values
  data[[value_col]] <- as.factor(round(data[[value_col]]))
  
  # Define the colors you want to use. You should probably use a predefined color palette to make things look nice
  color_palette <- rainbow(length(breaks))
  
  # Create the heatmap using ggplot
  ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = data[[value_col]])) +
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = setNames(color_palette, as.character(breaks)),
      breaks = breaks,
      labels = ifelse(breaks %% label_interval == 0, as.character(breaks), "")
    )
}
```

then just call the function to make the plot:

```
heatmap <- heatmapper(data, value_col = "value", label_interval = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! So you think there is no other «legend-label» waiver-like setting, and that this must be done manually? I have many different parameters and stations to plot, and was hoping that the bin functionality was developed to handle continuous data in this very way, and that the legend would be “prettier” by default.

Comment: I added a generic solution above that I hope is helpful

Comment: I see you have presented the same solution as stefan, but I can only mark one answer as the solution, and he provided a shorter one using my scale_fill. I still appreciate your help! :)